# Pipe guarantee to close after the child has exited

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup2

In the code below, is it safe to rely on **read() failure** to detect termination of child?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
   int pipefd[2];
   pipefd[0] = 0;
   pipefd[1] = 0;
   pipe(pipefd);

   pid_t pid = fork();

   if (pid == 0)
   {
      // child
      close(pipefd[0]);    // close unused read end
      while ((dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) {}             // send stdout to the pipe
      while ((dup2(pipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) {} // send stderr to the pipe
      close(pipefd[1]);    // close unused write end

      char *argv[3];
      argv[0] = "worker-app";
      argv[1] = NULL;
      argv[2] = NULL;
      execvp("./worker-app", argv);
      printf("failed to execvp, errno %d\n", errno);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else if (pid == -1)
   {
   }
   else
   {
      // parent
      close(pipefd[1]);  // close the write end of the pipe in the parent

      char buffer[1024];
      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
      while (1) // <= here is it safe to rely on read below to break from this loop ?
      {
        ssize_t count = read(pipefd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
        printf("pipe read return %d\n", (int)count);
        if (count > 0)
        {
          printf("child: %s\n", buffer);
        }
        else if (count == 0)
        {
          printf("end read child pipe\n", buffer);
          break;
        }
        else if (count == -1)
        {
          if (errno == EINTR)
          {   continue;
          }
          printf("error read child pipe\n", buffer);
          break;
        }
      }

      close(pipefd[0]); // close read end, prevent descriptor leak

      int waitStatus = 0;
      waitpid(pid, &waitStatus, 0);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "All work completed :-)\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Should I add something in the while(1) loop to detect child termination? What specific scenario could happen and break this app ?

Some thoughts of improvements below. However would I just waste CPU cycles?

1. Use kill with special argument 0 that won't kill the process but just check if it is responsive:
   `if (kill(pid, 0)) { break; /* child exited */ };`
   /* If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID or process group ID. https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill */
2. Use waitpid non-blocking in the while(1) loop to check if child has exited.
3. Use select() to check for pipe readability to prevent read() from possibly hanging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your ideas:

- If the child spawns children of its own, the `read()` won't return 0 until all of its descendants either die or close stdout and stderr. If it doesn't, or if the child always outlives all of its descendants, then just waiting for `read()` to return 0 is good enough and won't ever cause a problem.
- If the child dies but the parent hasn't yet `wait(2)`ed on it, then `kill(pid, 0)` will succeed as if the child were still alive (at least on Linux), so this isn't an effective check from within your parent program.
- A non-blocking `waitpid()` on its own would appear to fix the problem with the child having children of its own, but would actually introduce a subtle race condition. If the child exited right after the `waitpid()` but before the `read()`, then the `read()` would block until the rest of the descendants exited.
- On its own, if you used `select()` in a blocking way, it's no better than just calling `read()`. If you used `select()` in a non-blocking way, you'd just end up burning CPU time in a loop.

What I'd do:

- Add a no-op signal handler function for SIGCHLD, just so that it causes EINTR when it occurs.
- Block SIGCHLD in the parent before you start looping.
- Use non-blocking `read`s, and use `pselect(2)` to block to avoid spinning the CPU forever.
- During the `pselect`, pass in a `sigset_t` that doesn't have SIGCHLD blocked, so that it's guaranteed to cause an EINTR for it when it eventually gets sent.
- Somewhere in the loop, do a non-blocking `waitpid(2)`, and handle its return appropriately. (Make sure you do this at least once after blocking SIGCHLD but before calling `select` for the first time, or you'll have a race condition.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you sure about "Use non-blocking reads, and use pselect(2) to block to avoid spinning the CPU forever.". In my benchmark the blocking read() did not had measurable impact on performances.

Comment: What scenario can be prevented with the use of SIGCHLD as you describe?

Comment: @theconstantgardener Re CPU usage, the "spin forever" scenario would only happen if you used non-blocking reads without pselect, which is what I was warning against. Blocking reads would be fine with regards to CPU.

Comment: @theconstantgardener Re SIGCHLD, the idea is to make sure an EINTR happens to let your program out of the select call when the child dies.